# Change supported orientation in UIViewController programmatically Apportable

Tags: android, ios, apportable

I'm using [apportable](https://www.apportable.com) to port my iOS app on Android.

I have two versions of user interface. One has screen rotation and other has just portrait mode. I make decision which version to use in method

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;
```

based on physical screen size. My app starts only in portrait mode, then in one of my cases I need unlock other orientations. Any ideas what can I try?
I've already try Android SDK method

```
activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER);
```

it works, but I don't receive

```
- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

Following method have been never invoke as well

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
```